# Which one the is more appropriate predictive model to use in R for the following scenario

Tags: r, lm

I have values in x axis ranging from 300 mm to 0.075 mm, and in y - axis from 0 to 100. I need to predict the values for x = 0.002. There is a need to plot using semilog plot. I tried to use `lm` function in the following way:

```
f2 <- data.frame(sievesize = c(0.075, 1.18, 2.36, 4.75), weight = c(55, 66.9, 67.69, 75)
f3 <- data.frame(sievesize = 0.002)
model1 <- lm(weight ~ log10(sievesize), data = f2)
pred3 <- predict(model1, f3)
```

Is there any better way to predict the values for 0.002?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do much with the data except to calculate the prediction interval to understand what is a margin of error for your prediction (it will be shown that it is 38.5 mm +/- 21 mm):

- just four points in a range of your experimental data (~ 18 bytes of data).
- 0.002 mm sieve size is outside your data range [0.075, 4.75]. Unfortunately this kind of extrapolation of any model leads to quate a huge prediction error.
- non-linear relation you are fitting in lin-log plot has a discontinuity when approach to zero
- the data are distributed in a very narrow range for an exponential dependence.

Please see below the code:

```
f2 <- data.frame(sievesize = c(0.075, 1.18, 2.36, 4.75), weight = c(55, 66.9, 67.69, 75))
f3 <- data.frame(sievesize = c(0.002))

m_lm <- lm(weight ~ log10(sievesize), data = f2)
fit_lm <- predict(m_lm, f3, interval = "prediction")
fit_lm

pred_x <- data.frame(sievesize = seq(0.001, 5, .01))
fit_conf <- predict(m_lm, pred_x, interval = "prediction")
# fit      lwr      upr
# 1 38.46763 17.73941 59.19586

plot(log10(f2$sievesize), f2$weight, ylim = c(0, 85), pch = 16, xlim = c(-3, 1))
points(log10(f3$sievesize), fit_lm[, 1], col = "red", pch = 16)
lines(log10(pred_x$sievesize), fit_conf[, 1])
lines(log10(pred_x$sievesize), fit_conf[, 2], col = "blue")
lines(log10(pred_x$sievesize), fit_conf[, 3], col = "blue")
legend("bottomright",
       legend = c("experiment", "fitted line", "prediction interval", "forecasted"),
       lty = c(NA, 1, 1, NA), 
       lwd = c(NA, 1, 1, NA),
       pch = c(16, NA, NA, 16), 
       col = c("black", "black", "blue", "red"))
```

and the graph which illustrates above mentioned points:
[image: graph]

So the usage some advance techniques like nonlinear fit, glm or bayessian regression etc. will not bring additional insights as the data set is extriemly small and distributed in very narrow range.

Comment: we have a good database of earlier records from which there is a possibility on extrapolating on the curve for <=0.002 mm.For example the Coefficient of curvature(Cc) will depend on amount of flaky particles whose behavior is quite different from +0.02 mm.If we could establish a  relation between the Coefficient of curvature of the characteristics which causes the deviant behavior such as plasticity index,liquid limit then we may extrapolate and have forecast with the model which has  Cc,liquid limit and pl.For silt size(+0.02) is it possible to predict using the current model?

Comment: Dear srinivas,  from your explanations it seems that you can use some non-linear multivariate analysis. However without actual data it is quite difficult to judge and generally [extrapolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrapolation#Extrapolation_arguments) results are strongly dependent on a kind of model used.